# Ionic Jade mask text input

Tags: ionic-framework, input, pug, text-mask

I'm building an iOS app using Ionic and am using Jade for UI. There is an input box that I want the value typed to be masked. The input could be numeric or numeric+alphabetical. So far, I couldn't find how to do it.

Anyone can help what should I do to mask the input while user is typing?  For example, if user type '123', what should be shown in UI is 'XXX'. And I would need the unmasked value as well when I submit to API.

Any example would be useful as well since I'm not too familiar with ionic and jade.

UPDATE:

it is like the password input text field. When user types in the password, in the UI, instead of the real character typed by user, you will see "...." or "XXXX"...this is the effect that I want.

Answer (score 0):

For mask you can use

> npm angular2-text-mask

**In input set:**

```
[textMask]="{mask: mask,  guide: false, modelClean: true}"
```

**In .ts file set rgex :**

```
mask: any[] = ['+', /\d/, ' ', '(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/];
```

Comment: this isn't really what I want...I don't care about the format..I just want whenever user types in an input field, in screen, instead of the character typed, it will show as "X", but I must be able to get the real character that is typed by user.

Example, if user type "save" in input box, on screen, it will show as "XXXX", and in  javascript file, I will be able to get the value "save" since it needs to be submitted into API. Of course would have to take account if backspace is used to delete.